# Get Element from awesomium webcontrol in c#

Tags: javascript, awesomium

I need to get the 'p' element and I use the following code

> dynamic document = webControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document");
>    var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

but it doesn't work 
I use Awesomium v1.7.5.1  with visual studio 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What specific data do you need from those paragraphs?
In the current example that I posted below gets the innerHTML of the each paragraph. The javascript could be:

```
function GetContents() {
    var arr = [];
    var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
         arr.push(paragraphs[i].innerHTML);
    }
    return arr;
} 
GetContents();
```

and you can execute this directly by:

```
JSObject paragraphs = webControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("function GetContents() {var arr = [];var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {arr.push(paragraphs[i].innerHTML);}return arr;} GetContents();")
```

In my case however, it seems that I keep on getting an undefined content for the variable paragraphs. The work around for me is putting the `GetContents()` inside an `alert()` function.

It becomes this:

```
JSObject paragraphs = webControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("function GetContents() {var arr = [];var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {arr.push(paragraphs[i].innerHTML);}return arr;} alert(GetContents());")
```

and you'll need to wait for the event `webControl1.ShowJavascriptDialog` to fire.

In Visual Basic.NET, you can do:

```
Private Sub JSDialog(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As JavascriptDialogEventArgs) Handles webControl1.ShowJavascriptDialog
    e.Cancel = False
    e.Handled = True
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message)
End Sub
```

In C#, you can do it by creating the function:

```
private void JSDialog(object sender, JavascriptDialogEventArgs e) {
    e.Cancel = false;
    e.Handled = true;
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```

and add this:

```
webControl1.ShowJavascriptDialog += OnShowJavascriptDialog;
```

Comment: thank :)
I need to get the innertext and store it in C# variable not to alert it .

Comment: Ah nice to hear. Although the alert part is just an alternative if the first method doesn't work as it didn't work here in my side. The JSDialog function's e.Message contains the data which you alerted in JS. Cheers!

Comment: thanks 
but I need to manipulate individual element of tag 'p' and may modify or delete one of them

Comment: Yes, it's actually possible. The thing to modify will be on the GetContents() function in JS. Specifically, the line: arr.push(paragraphs[i].innerHTML);

You can possibly add a delimiter like '|' or any special character so it will be: arr.push(paragraphs[i].innerHTML + "|"); and then you split the result in C# to get an array result which contain each paragraphs.